# git rebase interactively all commits on my branch since master

Tags: git, git-rebase

I tried:

```
$ git rebase -i --onto master mybranch
$ git rebase -i master mybranch
$ git rebase -i mybranch master
$ git rebase -i --onto master master mybranch
$ git rebase -i  `git merge-base mybranch master`
```

They are noops. What is the command (instead of counting the commits on `mybranch` since `master` and issuing a `git rebase -i HEAD~num`) ?

Comment: Could you add an ASCII graph showing the state of your repo (showing, in particular, where `master` and `mybranch` point to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git rebase -i <sha1>` where sha1 will be the desired commit to start rebasing

As mentioned by @Mr_and_Mrs_D the exact answer is `git rebase -i master`

Be sure to have an up-to-date ***local*** master branch and to issue the command from your (clean) `mybranch` though.

Comment: -1 wasn't mine - and whoever did it should comment - actually I had tried `git rebase -i master` which should work but for some reason didn't - the reason was that I had no local `master` branch. So add this info to your answer and I will accept (no `git rebase -i <sha1>` not needed - keep it but `git rebase -i master` is the way to go (no unnecessary fiddling with SHAs)